# problema al instalar oracle en debian

Tags: linux, oracle, debian

Tengo un problema al tratar de instalar oracle 12c release 2 en debian estuve buscando tutos en linea que me complicaron la vida, y ahora que quiero correr ./runInstaller me sale el siguiente error.

No tiene suficientes permisos para acceder al inventario '/home/oracle/app/oraInventory'. No se puede continuar con la instalación. Es necesario que el grupo primario del usuario de instalación sea igual que el grupo del propietario del inventario. Asegúrese de que el usuario de instalación forma parte del grupo del propietario del inventario y reinicie Installer.

espero puedan ayudarme de antemano gracias.

Comment: Has probado a cambiar tu usuario a root antes de ejecutar el comando runInstaller? Si es así quizás tengas que dar permiso de ejecución al comando con chmod 755 runInstaller

Comment: Revisa que tengas privilegios al inventario en la ruta que viene ahi.
¿Con que usuario estas instalando Oracle? Por lo que veo deberia de ser el usuario "oracle. ¿a que grupo pertenece el usuario "oracle"?
¿Que privilegios tiene el usuario en el inventario?

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta en que estas ejecutando runinstaller desde tu user normal, pero Oracle solo trabaja con sus propios usuarios, por lo tanto, en caso de que no lo hayas probado ya, intenta ejecutar .runinstaller desde el usuario oracle, o en todo caso, si ya lo estas haciendo desde oracle, intenta que este user este dentro del grupo orainventory.

Answer (score 1):

Hola recuerda que al instalar **Oracle** tienes que crear algunos usuarios en especial el usuario **oracle**; una vez que lo hayas creado y dado los privilegios adecuados la instalación del runinstaler deber realizarlos con ese usuario no con **root**.

Saludos